# Getting back to a page with Infinite scroll to the exact same point where the user left it

Tags: reactjs

I used react-infinite-scroll-component it's working just fine.
However, I want to avoid making the user lose his scroll position when he leaves the page and clicks back?
Also please put on consideration Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure because I haven't used it - but since no one else has chimed in... the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component) say the component has a prop named `key` that is described as:

> the key for the current data set being shown, used when the same
>   component can show different data sets at different times,
>   default=undefined

Also, it has a prop named `onScroll` that is described as:

> a function that will listen to the scroll event on the scrolling
>   container. Note that the scroll event is throttled, so you may not
>   receive as many events as you would expect.

... which I suspect one of the arguments of which will tell you which keys it loaded / scrolled through.

So my approach would be to use componentWillUnmount to save the last key it loaded into a parent property (*or Redux store if you're using Redux*)... and when the component loads, if the `key` exists in the parent (*or Redux store if you're using Redux*) then pass it that key.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate on it..? I have saved the last key, but get lost what to do with `onScroll` next.